# Adding border-radius to Table displays page abnormally in IE

Tags: html, css

I had few pages with normal table border which were working fine until I changed the code to display rounded radius and it affected whole layout of the page. This problem is occurring only in IE on web server. It works fine in IE when launched on local server. Code works fine in Chrome and FF all the time.

```
<table style="background-color: Snow; margin-top: 20px; border: 2px solid #cccccc;-webkit-border-radius: 20px;-moz-border-radius: 20px;border-radius: 20px;">
```

One thing I observed is that in Developer Tools of IE, now the page gets loaded in Quirks Mode by default. However when I change Document Mode to IE9 Standards, the page gets fixed.
The DOCTYPE I'm using is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Faulty page can be seen at [link](http://www.42gears.com/surelock/surelockandroid.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a comment before your DOCTYPE. This is not allowed, at least in IE. I don't know what the standards say about it, but that's the reason you're in Quirks Mode.

EDIT: You also have `<script>`s outside the `<html>` element... That won't help.